# Webcomic where aliens were going to destroy Earth for not being technically advanced. Involved roller skates bridged by a Slinky

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I was reading an article about the Segway, and I was suddenly reminded of a webcomic panel. When the Segway was being announced, hyperbole was being used like "this will render forms of transportation like cars and trains obsolete". In the webcomic, aliens had threatened to destroy the Earth if we didn't show our technological worthiness, and Earth is pinning its hopes on a fellow using a very similar line to that for Segway. The protagonists break into a warehouse where the invention is being stocked, and despair the fate of Earth since it's such a dumb invention. Cue the final panel of that day's strip showing the protagonist skating down the sidewalk in a set of the skates and whooping with joy.

I probably read it in the early 2000s. I think the comic was black and white and the protagonist was an attractive female (I'm kind of picturing something like [Francine Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francine_Smith) from *American Dad*). The style was cartoonish but not grotesque. I think the concept behind the skates (either stated or indicated by motion lines in that final panel) was that the oscillating spring would bring the skaters legs in and out as they skated.

I'm pretty sure the protagonists knew about the aliens (maybe even knew some) before the events of this arc. I don't believe Earth was destroyed, and the strip went on

Comment: Name one comic where the protagonist is female but not attractive :P

Comment: @DKNguyen - Squirrel girl was originally [fairly homely](https://miro.medium.com/max/656/0*CdybjsAUToKNVGzZ.PNG). They've [sexified her](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/9/97/U.S.Avengers_Vol_1_1_Textless.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160920161132) in recent years though

Comment: I consider the cat already obsolete as a form of transportation.

Comment: @Valorum Just a little.

Comment: @DKNguyen Broom-Hilda?

Comment: @user14111 You win...this time.

Comment: Fixed some types. Danged phone autocorrect.